# Incomplete APK file

Tags: android, export, apk, sign

I'm using MyEclipse 2015, and the newest ADT. 
When exporting android project to .apk (eclipse=>Export=>Export android application) file I had incomplete files structures inside apk, something like this:

```
 = META-INF 
    ===CERT.RSA
    ===CERT.SF
    ===MANIFEST.MF
 = classes.dx
```

And it's all. It's very strange because application work correctly on device when I run it from eclipse, and structure generated apk file in bin folder is complete.

Comment: Can you install this apk  ?

Comment: I can't install generated apk, only from debugging mode from eclipse work correctly.

Comment: Is it because you don't have release signing cert setup for your project?  I'd suggest creating an ant build file for your project; create the necessary certificates and then run 'ant release'

Comment: Could be bad build tools. Anyway Google is no longer supporting any other IDE but Android Studio and this support includes the latest ADT. You should migrate and see if you still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user1524658, I think you tried to sign the app and export it. Make sure this certificate is created properly and try this certificate with any other android app and see if the same certificate works in that application.
Since it is getting installed in from eclipse to device directly, there is no problem with apk creation.

Comment: Export with this key on android studio works properly, only on eclipse+adt this error occured